# published webapi in Azure comes under PaaS and IaaS?

Tags: azure, service

I published a web api in Azure via Visual Studio. I would like to know if it is PaaS or IaaS.

When I search for the answer, I find lot of definitions about the PaaS and IaaS.

But I did not find where it is clearly defined which services found in Azure portal are PaaS and Which are IaaS?

Thanks.
With best regards,
SR

Answer (score 1):

**IaaS** (Infrastructure as a Service):

> Cloud infrastructure services, known as Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS), are made of highly scalable and automated compute resources. IaaS is fully self-service for accessing and monitoring things like compute, networking, storage, and other services, and it allows businesses to purchase resources on-demand and as-needed instead of having to buy hardware outright.

**PaaS** (Platform as a Service):

> Cloud platform services, or Platform as a Service (PaaS), provide cloud components to certain software while being used mainly for applications. PaaS provides a framework for developers that they can build upon and use to create customized applications. All servers, storage, and networking can be managed by the enterprise or a third-party provider while the developers can maintain management of the applications.

Source: [SaaS vs PaaS vs IaaS: What’s The Difference and How To Choose](http://bmc.com/blogs/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-choose/)

In short: with IaaS you use *infrastructure* (mostly VMs, networking, ...) from your cloud provider that you manage yourself. With PaaS you use an abstraction layer on top of some infrastructure where you *do not* manage the underlying infrastructure itself. You only manage the application and its data.

If you've deployed to an App Service, you're using PaaS. If you've deployed to a VM that you manage and runs IIS, you're using IaaS.

Another interesting read: [What is PaaS?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-paas/)